# File 'someFile.java' is ignored. It is not located in project basedir 'D:\HybrisSuites\HYBRISCOMM6400P\hybris\bin\platform'

Tags: sonarqube, sap-commerce-cloud

Recently we were migrated SonarQube-6.3 to SonarQube7.9. From the Hybris side we are using sonar.xml is ant build file.

When we ran the sonar via ant command is ant sonar
we are getting the below issues.
[sonar:sonar] File 'someFile.java' is ignored. It is not located in project basedir 'D:\HybrisSuites\HYBRISCOMM6400P\hybris\bin\platform'.

based on the sonar.xml, we are mentioned the sonar properties in local.properties file.

```
sonar.projectName=TE
    sonar.projectKey=TE
    sonar.projectVersion=1.0
    sonar.verbose=true
    sonar.language=java
    sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
    sonar.scm.disabled=True
    sonar.host.url=http://localhost:8000
    sonar.java.source=1.8     sonar.excludedExtensions=core,testweb,b2bacceleratoraddon,hystrixaddon,oauth2,embeddedserver,tomcatembeddedserver,platformbackoffice,voucherbackoffice,backofficesolrsearch,pcmbackoffice,promotionsbackoffice,ticketsystembackoffice,adaptivesearch,ordercalculation,webservicescommons,solrfacetsearchbackoffice,basecommercebackoffice,ruleengine,ruleengineservices,ruledefinitions,ruleenginebackoffice,b2bcommercefacades,b2bapprovalprocessfacades,droolsruleengineservices,promotionengineservices,promotionenginebackoffice,couponservices,couponwebservices,couponfacades,couponbackoffice,rulebuilderbackoffice,solrserver,commerceservicesbackoffice,customersupportbackoffice,adaptivesearchbackoffice,adaptivesearchsolr,warehousing,commerceorgaddon,paymetric,scripting,paymentstandard,mediaweb,maintenanceweb,deliveryzone,commons,processing,impex,validation,catalog,europe1,platformservices,workflow,hac,comments,advancedsavedquery,springintegrationlibs,ldap,hmc,virtualjdbc,cockpit,admincockpit,reportcockpit,platformhmc,productcockpit,customerreview,sapcoretest,sapcoreodata,sapcore,sapcorejco,sapcorejcorec,sapcorebol,advancedexport,backoffice,datahubbackoffice,mcc,wishlist,mediaconversion,solrfacetsearch,solrfacetsearchhmc,voucher,promotions,basecommerce,ticketsystem,cms2,cms2lib,btg,cmscockpit,btgcockpit,b2bcommerce,payment,commerceservices,b2bapprovalprocess,commercewebservicescommons,cscockpit,acceleratorservices,b2bacceleratorservices,acceleratorcms,commercefacades,acceleratorfacades,acceleratorstorefrontcommons,b2bacceleratorfacades,addonsupport,sapcoreaddon,captchaaddon,liveeditaddon,commercesearch,commercesearchhmc,commercesearchbackoffice,datahubadapter,sapcoreconfiguration,sapmodel,sapproductavailability,sapproductavailabilityhmc,b2bsapproductavailability,sappricingbol,sappricinghmc,sappricing,sappricingproductcarouseladdon,b2bsappricing,sapcustomerb2c,sapcustomerb2b,sapmodelhmc,saporderexchange,saporderexchangeb2b,sapcoreconfigurationhmc,sapproducthmc,sapcoreconfigurationbackoffice,multipaymentmode,amazonpay,codpayment,bspay,paypalservice,acceleratorcmshmc,warehousingwebservices,npmancillary,acceleratorwebservicesaddon,commerceserviceshmc,yaddon,customerticketingfacades,consignmenttrackingservices,ordermanagementwebservices,ordermanagementaddon,sap,promotionenginesamplesaddon,cmsfacades,consignmenttrackingfacades,ordermanagementfacade,warehousingfacade,samlsinglesignon,ycommercewebservices,consignmenttrackingaddon,ycommercewebservices,ycommercewebserviceshmc,acceleratorserviceshmc,customerticketingaddon,orderselfserviceaddon,asynchronousOM,saporderexchangehmc,saporderexchangebackoffice

    sonar.global.exclusions= **/gensrc/**/*.java ,**/mobile/**/*.java,**/v1/**/*.java
    sonar.exclusions=**/gensrc/**/*.java ,**/mobile/**/*.java,**/v1/**/*.java
    sonar.sources=D:/HybrisSuites/HYBRISCOMM6400P/hybris/bin/custom/te/tecore/src
    sonar.java.binaries=D:/HybrisSuites/HYBRISCOMM6400P/hybris/bin/custom/te/tecore/classes
```

Can you please let me know is there any properties i missed?

Answer (score 0):

This will only scan under the base directory, so all files that are not under the base directory will be ignored

```
sonar.projectBaseDir=D:\HybrisSuites\HYBRISCOMM6400P\hybris\bin\platform
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation on what this does?

Comment: It will only scan under the base directory, so all files that are not under the base directory will be ignored. Hope this can help you